# How to dual boot ubuntu and windows 10 on dell inspiron 7472

Tags: boot, dual-boot, usb, dell, live-usb

I am attempting to dual boot ubuntu 18.0.4 with windows 10 on my new dell inspiron 7472, and i was following this guide: [Dell guide](https://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/04/sln301754/how-to-install-ubuntu-and-windows-8-or-10-as-a-dual-boot-on-your-dell-pc?lang=en). I followed all the steps up until I was told to boot from my bootable usb drive, created with rufus with GPT. whenever I enter the boot menu, the bootable medium is not displayed, I have tried flashing it with both MBR and GPT to no avail.

Is there a step I have missed?

EDIT: I have managed to boot from usb by using etcher with a different USB, however there when i click install, it only shows the option to install to the USB itself, and doesnt show the installation type window

Comment: Try creating Bootable usb with Etcher. Rufus has lot of unnecessary options. Get it from etcher.io

Comment: @harshit Thanks, this has gotten me further but a new problem still awaits

Comment: Almost all Dell need UEFI update, if SSD, SSD firmware update and then settings in UEFI changes. Drives need ot be AHCI, not RAID. And if dual booting with Windows install the AHCI driver first. Turn off fast start up in Windows.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI & http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-10-with-uefi  & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi

Comment: @oldfred Changing to AHCI bricked my device, I attempted to install the drivers then change my SATA operation, however it simply led to me being forced to factory reset my device.

Comment: Factory reset will change all your UEFI settings. I have 5 or 7 that I change, so keep a list. Did you install AHCI drivers into Windows first. The only time to stay with RAID is if you have RAID 0.

Comment: @oldfred Yes I installed all the drivers first, I have "Raid On"

Comment: I have only seen one post where user claimed he had RAID on, and it worked. Every other set of instructions for Dell by Dell & users have had to change to AHCI.  Only server install has all the RAID drivers.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem and after reading above post first I tried to do as explained by @oldfred which involves a few steps:

- set disk access to AHCI instead of Raid in BIOS
- turn off safe boot in BIOS
- turn off fast boot in Windows

Unfortunately I ran into the same issue that @BastiatAdmin described in that it stopped the machine from booting Windows and the Ubuntu installation software could still not see the disk on the machine.

However, instead of doing a factory reset I let Windows recover itself after which I ended up with a Windows installation that was running off of AHCI as suggested by @oldfred.

At this point I was able to simply press F12 during startup and boot off my Ubuntu USB stick and install the Ubuntu OS alongside Windows without any issues.

I realise the core issue is that a desktop install for Ubuntu does not support Raid and for that reason it won't see the drive. Changing the access initially stops windows from working and you still can't install Ubuntu alongside it for some reason. 
Letting Windows recover from the changed disk access seems to fix everything in the end.